# modify a full screen shader's resolution

Tags: opengl-es, shader

I found a nice shade on the shader toy site:

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4scGWj

It renders an animated laser horizontally the center of the screen :

[image]

What I want to do know is:

. to be able to specify the SIZE of the laser (say the screen is 800 * 600 and I hope the laser is rendered in a area of 80 * 60 - it looks like the laser is scaled)

and more :

. to be able to render the laser in between a given START POINT and a END POINT (say 100,100 to 400,400)

I tried to modify the shader but can not get it done, any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

These shaders on ShaderToy calculate the pixel values based on `fragCoord`.  If you use a transformed version of `fragCoord` instead, you can scale, rotate, or even deform the image.  Matrix transformations on `fragCoord` gives you an easy way to rotate and scale.

However, this will not give you a start point or an end point.  For that, you will have to understand how the shader works and make the changes yourself.

Another alternative is to render the laser to a single quad, rather than a full-screen quad, and use texture coordinates instead of `fragCoord`.